# How to share data between two separate modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to know how to sync data between two controllers in different modules. below is the code I'm using. I tried to use the service with the observer pattern. but it seems that the service instance injected on the two apps are quite different

```
angular.module('app3', []).service('sharedService', function () {
        this.Country = 'USA';
        this.scope = null;
        this. observerCallbacks = [];

        //register an observer
        this.registerObserverCallback = function (callback) {
            this.observerCallbacks.push(callback);
        };

        //call this when you know 'foo' has been changed
        this.notifyObservers = function () {
            alert('notifed');

            angular.forEach(this.observerCallbacks, function (callback) {
                console.log('notification');
                callback();
            });
        };
    })
    angular.module('app2', ['app3']).controller('app2Controller', function ($scope, $rootScope, sharedService) {
        console.log('Controller 2 loaded');
        var updateCountry = function () {
            $scope.MyCountry = sharedService.Country;
        };

        sharedService.registerObserverCallback(updateCountry);
        console.log(sharedService);
        // this needs lazy loading
        // $rootScope = sharedService.scope;

        // console.log(sharedService.Country);
        // $scope.MyCountry = sharedService.Country;
    })
    angular.module('app1',['app1','app3']).controller('app1Controller',function($scope,$rootScope,sharedService)
    {
        $scope.Countries = ['Egypt', 'KSA'];
        $scope.Country = '';
        sharedService.scope = $rootScope;
        $scope.DrpChange = function () {
            //$stateParams.Country = $scope.Country;
            //$state.current.params.Country = $scope.Country;
            //console.log($state.current.params.Country);
            console.log(sharedService);
            sharedService.Country = $scope.Country;
            sharedService.notifyObservers();
            // this is not working because the rootscope is not shared
            $rootScope.$emit("Country.changed", $scope.Country);
        }
    })



    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ['app2']);
```

see HTML at http://embed.plnkr.co/l0utIMp27qpbsao64Api/

Comment: Should be same instance. What is specific problem?

Comment: Actually they are not the same, the log of the console shows that they're different. the problem will be resolved if we have the same reference in both of the controllers.   Object {Country: "USA", scope: Scope, observerCallbacks: Array[0]}
Object {Country: "KSA", scope: Scope, observerCallbacks: Array[0]}

Comment: Create a demo that replicates whatever problem you have

Comment: here is http://embed.plnkr.co/l0utIMp27qpbsao64Api/

Comment: @MahmoudShaaban See dear, your code looks messy a lot and it's incomplete too. So I'll show you a way how to share data b/w two different angular module. It's an easy example and after that you could modify it and use it for your purpose... If it helps you then accept it and vote up. Please... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating 2 completely separate angular apps. That's why you're getting 2 instances. You want 1 app with 3 modules.

First take out `angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ['app2']);` from `index.html`. You're bootstrapping a second app there. Not what you want.

Next, move `ng-app="app1"` to an element that contains both controllers like the `body` element.

Also, in `index.html` change `{{myCounty}}` to `{{MyCounty}}`. Case matters.

Finally in `app.js` change `angular.module('app1',['app1','app3'])` to `angular.module('app1',['app2','app3'])`. I think that was what you meant to do in the first place.

Also, please post your index.html contents in the question. A lot of the problems were in there. That way, if your link dies at some point, this question may still be helpful to others with similar problems.

Here is a working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8vKMPe31U3FgVvvPc0Xh?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is what I need exactly!  I had to add the module as a dependency.

Answer (score -3):

here's an demo/example showing a way to share data between tow different angular module : **You should modify the code and use it according to your need/purpose** :

```
angular.module('app.A', [])
.service('ServiceA', function() {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return this.myValue;
    };

    this.setValue = function(newValue) {
        this.myValue = newValue;
    }
});

angular.module('app.B', ['app.A'])
.service('ServiceB', function(ServiceA) {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return ServiceA.getValue();
    };

    this.setValue = function() {
        ServiceA.setValue('New value');
    }
});
```

**Thanks & Cheers :-)**